# Behavior of Asterisk(*) in Azure Search Service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to know how * works in azure search service. Currently I created index for my data and am querying by giving following data in "search" field in json.

1. "search": "ATM" (Simple text)
2. "search":"ATM*" (with wild card)
3. "search":"ATM\*"(escaping the * to match elements with * but it's not working)

But in all cases I am getting same result. I want to know how *(or any other special character) is interpreted in Azure search.

If all of them are giving same result, which one should I use to gain maximum performance?

Thanks

Adding more details:

I have the following entries: 
ATM, ATM 1, ATM 2, ATM*

In all 3 cases I am getting these 4 results. In first case, it should return only 1 result( ATM); in second case all results; and in 3rd case ATM*.

Comment: Can you describe the result you're expecting and the actual result you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that all three search queries return identical results in this case.

At indexing, documents go through lexical analysis. Texts in the documents are tokenized into terms and additional processing such as removal of symbols and punctuations, and stemming/lemmatization is done. Assuming you are using the standard analyzer which is the default, you will get the following tokens from the doc contents :

doc1. ATM => atm

doc2. ATM 1 => atm, 1

doc3. ATM 2 => atm, 2

doc5. ATM* => atm (punctuations and symbols discarded by default)

The term tokens are stored in the inverted index and used in finding documents that contain the terms.

At query time, search queries also go through the same analysis process. The standard analyzer normalizes (lowercases) terms and discards punctuations. Thus, both of the search queries "ATM" and "ATM*" are analyzed to atm and return the same results. The wildcard search query "ATM*" go through a slightly different path. The wildcard prefix query expands to terms in the inverted index that start with the prefix. So, if you had 'ATM1' and 'ATM2' (no spaces) in the documents, the wild search query 'ATM*' would have matched those as well.

Wildcard search queries (ATM*) are usually much slower than exact search queries (ATM or ATM*) due to the query expansion process.

Also, if you need to be able to find terms with special characters ('*', for example), please take a look at [custom analysis in Azure Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt605304.aspx). We offer different ways for users to customize the analysis chain.

Nate